# Selenium Google Places Autocomplete Java

Tags: java, selenium, autocomplete

I am trying to automate Google auto suggestion and selecting a random suggestion using Selenium.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='id_address']"));
element.sendKeys(“whi”);
```

How to select a random suggestion from the list of Google suggestions ?

Comment: I tried 
**element.sendKeys(Keys.Down)**
 which highlights the third item in the list but it didnt get clicked eventhough click() is used.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find all the matching elements that represent auto-complete suggestion options. Since the appearance of auto complete suggestions is asynchronous, you need to wait for them to appear using a loop or a `WebDriverWait`. The line that gets the `List<WebElement>` list will keep trying to find elements that match the given selector and will only return when the list (from the `driver.findElements` call that it wraps) is not empty. If it doesn't find a non-empty list in the given timeout (`10` seconds in this case from the `WebDriverWait` constructor) it will throw a `TimeoutException`. Then, once you have the list of suggestions, it's a simple matter of selecting a random one from that list and clicking on it.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.findElement(By.name("q"))
      .sendKeys("whi");
List<WebElement> options = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBeMoreThan(By.cssSelector("[role='option']"), 0));
int index = (int) (Math.random() * options.size());
options.get(index)
       .click();
```

Comment: How to select the place from the list displaying. What should be given for role and option of cssSelector? I am not able to get the xpath of the google places list. Please let me know where i m going wrong

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. For regular google search auto suggestions then the code I posted should work. If it doesn't for you, then right click on any of the suggestions you see and inspect them in the developer console of your browser. By looking at the DOM elements you can figure out the right locators to use.